# Make all the textboxes in a html form end at the same point

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the form look as in the screenshot below. The textboxes should start immediately after the text and all of them should end at the same point.

[image]

My existing markup is below:

```css
 .txtbig {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-image: none; width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableBody1" colspan="4">
        <strong>Intended Recipient Information</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name and Title
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpNameTitle" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpNameTitle" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td style="width: 11px;">
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator23"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Company Name and Division</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpCompanyNameDiv" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpCompanyNameDiv" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator24"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Complete Mailing Address</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpCompleteMailAddress" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpCompleteMailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator25"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Direct Telephone No.</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpDirectTelNo" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpDirectTelNo" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator26"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Email Address</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpEmailAddress" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpEmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator27"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Intended Application</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpIntendedApp" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpIntendedApp" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator28"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Appreciate your suggestions on the same.

Comment: Impossible to do the way you did it in a table. The table column will automatically size to a width at minimum the same width as the widest label. Try putting them in one table element and using the <label> tag instead of just text

Comment: You shouldn't use table for layout purposes, use only for tabular data!

Comment: table, tr, tr display can be reset and flex used for a first approach/test. label and fieldset would do a great job here indeed

Answer (score 0):

Consider do this layout using bootstrap!

see this link:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: I agree to your solution but I've to redesign the entire html page to design the layout using bootstrap. It also consumes lot of time for me. So, looking for a solution that includes my existing approach i.e. with tables.

Answer (score 0):

Well use the following css:

```
table tr td:first-child{
  width:20%; //editable as per your design requirement
}
```

this will set a fix width to all first td of table and other td will come in same width that means your textarea will come in same width

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Display:flex` and rewrite HTML **or reset display values of table elements (see second snippet for this**):

```css
div {
  border: solid;
}
p {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  margin: 0;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
}
/* fun */

p:nth-child(even) {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
        <strong>Intended Recipient Information</strong>
</h1>
  <p>
    Name and Title
    <input name="txtRecpNameTitle" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpNameTitle" type="text" maxlength="255"><span id="RequiredFieldValidator23"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Company Name and Division
    <input name="txtRecpCompanyNameDiv" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpCompanyNameDiv" type="text" maxlength="255">
    <span id="RequiredFieldValidator24"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Complete Mailing Address
    <input name="txtRecpCompleteMailAddress" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpCompleteMailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255">
    <span id="RequiredFieldValidator25"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Direct Telephone No.
    <input name="txtRecpDirectTelNo" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpDirectTelNo" type="text" maxlength="255">
    <span id="RequiredFieldValidator26"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span> 
  </p>
  <p>
    Email Address
    <input name="txtRecpEmailAddress" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpEmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255">
    <span id="RequiredFieldValidator27"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Intended Application
    <input name="txtRecpIntendedApp" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpIntendedApp" type="text" maxlength="255">
    <span id="RequiredFieldValidator28"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

```css
tr, 
[colspan="2"] {
  display:flex;
  }
td {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  }

[colspan],input { 
  flex:1;
  margin:0 0.125em
  }
/* fun */
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background:lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-image: none; width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tableBody1" colspan="4">
        <strong>Intended Recipient Information</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name and Title
      </td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpNameTitle" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpNameTitle" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td >
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator23"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Company Name and Division</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpCompanyNameDiv" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpCompanyNameDiv" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator24"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Complete Mailing Address</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpCompleteMailAddress" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpCompleteMailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator25"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Direct Telephone No.</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpDirectTelNo" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpDirectTelNo" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator26"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Email Address</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpEmailAddress" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpEmailAddress" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator27"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Intended Application</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input name="txtRecpIntendedApp" class="txtbig" id="txtRecpIntendedApp" type="text" maxlength="255">

      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="RequiredFieldValidator28"><img tabindex="-1" alt="Error Icon" src="../images/errorIcon.png"></span>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also agree that using bootstrap is probably the way to go. Here's a generic example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKjzoV

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```